# How can I train my dog to stop snorting at me?

Tags: dogs, training

My 4 year old male labrador snorts a lot especially when excited and/or holding a toy in his mouth. A lot of the time he's  facing people when he does this. It's pretty disgusting when you get hit in the face with it.

I believe this is just a reaction to irritants (such as dust etc) and perhaps a behaviour he's picked up due to being excited rather than a medical condition

How can I train him not to snort towards people?

Comment: A snort can be a friendly "hey, hi, look at me" sound. There may be nothing here that needs correcting.

Comment: I have not tried anything I wouldnt know where to start. It's  fairly predictable but not down to a small timeframe.

Comment: I'm not saying he's misbehaving. Its an undesirable behaviour. He expells a mist of snot from his nose onto your person. Very undesirable.

Comment: I'd ask a vet first.  It's possible the dog has allergies or some such that's causing him to be congested.  Other than that, I'd make sure to keep the dog's face away from your face, so at least you don't get blasted in the face.  If the dog specifically tries to get right in your face as dogs often do, you can at least train him out of that by pointedly turning away and ignoring him every time he tries.

Answer (score 1):

Training a replacement behavior can address issues like this. A replacement behavior in any behavior that is incompatible with the undesirable behavior. In this case, I suggest teaching him to stop and sit at a distance far enough away to be out of the 'spray zone'.